# Is it valid to have more than 1 <saml:assertions> in a SAML Token response

Tags: saml, json

I am trying to provide compatibility between an existing SAML token system with JWT token schema. The current system generates SAML tokens with a structure as follows:

Is it even valid to have more than one in a SAML token and if yes what would be the JWT representation for the below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:Response ID="aed9fa15c020fde" InResponseTo="acd3a67cb14a1d94" IssueInstant="2015-02-18T18:58:14.262Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">......</saml:Issuer>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
  </samlp:Status>
  <saml:Assertion ID="5d41027a4e2c2855" IssueInstant="2015-02-18T18:58:14.262Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">......</saml:Issuer>
    <saml:Subject>
      <saml:NameID NameQualifier="USER" SPProvidedID="1047259662">ab_idl1</saml:NameID>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2015-02-18T18:48:14.262Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-06-20T18:58:14.262Z"/>
  </saml:Assertion>
  <saml:Assertion ID="5ea9fbba7ab940c0" IssueInstant="2015-02-18T18:58:14.262Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <saml:Issuer>APPID-b1713f46d4e1</saml:Issuer>
    <saml:Subject>
      <saml:NameID NameQualifier="USER" SPProvidedID="1047259662">user_name_app_name</saml:NameID>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2015-02-18T18:48:14.262Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-06-20T18:58:14.262Z"/>
    <saml:AttributeStatement>
      <saml:Attribute FriendlyName="user_id1" Name="user_id">
        <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">user_name_app_name</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
    </saml:AttributeStatement>
  </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: I don't think JWTs have a notion of multiple assertions in the current spec.

Comment: Any suggestions for creating a structure. I own both the generation and validation parts of the token, however would like to align to a standard as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [section 4.1.4.2 of the spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf#page=18), it's legitimate to have multiple assertions in a response.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Could you please tell me what would be the JWT representation for the same structure with multiple assertions

Comment: I would if I could - it's beyond my skillset.

Comment: :) Thanks Andy. We are planning to use private claim names for the second assertion as part of the JWT.

Comment: You COULD pass a JWT as an attribute in the response - there's certainly nothing saying you can't... But I'm not sure that gets you where you need to go - ultimately, I'm not sure that I understand your use case.